Jewel thieves rappelling down front of glass building...?
... watched it on TV in the early 80s. At least two separate scenes gem thieves repelling down the face of a high-rise glass building.  In the latter scene, the rappelling pulley gets stuck, leaving one of the thieves dangling up there.  
There is also another scene where gems are hidden in the fuel tank or dump tank of a powerboat.  When the cops come on board the boat, the hero or the his girl has to dump the gems and there's a scene where the gems are falling to the bottom of the sea. 
Full color movie. Seemed not that old when I watched on tv in early 80s. 

The movie is Green Ice.
You can watch the part here where they hide the emeralds in the fish tank of their boat, there is the inspection, and the emeralds are released into the ocean.:



And here is the part where after the heist the two thiefs, one of them is played by Ryan O'Neal, rapell down the skyscraper and one of them, the Latin American revolutionary guy, played by Domingo Ambriz, gets stuck:




So not red at all...but green...and emeralds...not diamonds. Nice answer.

Thank you. I watched the movie in the 80's, liked it back at the time, and I immediately remembered the scenes the questioner described.
